# Rails: How to change image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

This is my javascript code:

```js
  //changing of eye icon of status
  $('.status-visible').on('click', (e) => {
    if ($(e.currentTarget.children[0]).attr('src') == '../assets/visible.png') {
      $(e.currentTarget.children[0]).attr('src', '../assets/notvisible.png');
      $(e.currentTarget).attr('uk-tooltip', 'Not Visible');
    }
    else {
      $(e.currentTarget.children[0]).attr('src', '../assets/visible.png');
      $(e.currentTarget).attr('uk-tooltip', 'Visible');
    }
  });
```

It works on local but when I uploaded it to heroku and run assets:precompile it will generate new imagename.

And this is my html code:

```html
<td>
                        <button class="uk-border-rounded status-visible" uk-tooltip='Visible'>
                          <img src="../assets/visible.png" class='uk-icon-image' />
                        </button>
                      </td>
```

Now, Every time that I have new assets and I run rails assets:precompile
it will generate new image path
so that it will not work on staging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the images to the `public/` folder and reference them directly:

```
  $('.status-visible').on('click', (e) => {
    if ($(e.currentTarget.children[0]).attr('src') == '/visible.png') {
      $(e.currentTarget.children[0]).attr('src', '/notvisible.png');
      $(e.currentTarget).attr('uk-tooltip', 'Not Visible');
    }
    else {
      $(e.currentTarget.children[0]).attr('src', '/visible.png');
      $(e.currentTarget).attr('uk-tooltip', 'Visible');
    }
  });
```

HTML

```
<td>
  <button class="uk-border-rounded status-visible" uk-tooltip='Visible'>
    <img src="/visible.png" class='uk-icon-image' />
  </button>
</td>
```

Comment: Is it okay to move the files there?

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine for small images like these